# How to transfer type work items (azure boards) from one project to another project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

**hypotheses:**

on Azdo we have 2 projects.

- Projet A

  ```
   With one board A.A
  ```
- Projet B

  ```
   With one Board B.B

   And other board B.B2
  ```

**How to configure ?**

How is it possible to create a bug or task type work item of a board A.A, and which transmits it to the baords of a project B.B.

The goal is for Team A to send bugs to Team B that another project needs to fix.
The status of the work item should also be syncronized in the 2 project teams of their own boards

Answer (score 1):

You could use Query under **Boards**-->**Queries**

**1)** create a new query to select all your required work items and then run the query

**2)** then select all work items under the query results and then click `...`--> **Move to team project**

[image]